# What does "errorStatus code 9" mean coming from the Looker SDK for Python and how to fix it?

Tags: python, looker-studio

I have

- some Looker Studio dashboards, accessible via: https://lookerstudio.google.com
- enabled the Looker Studio API
- created an OAuth client

I'd like to manage the dashboards using [looker-sdk](https://pypi.org/project/looker-sdk/), so I've created a

`looker.ini`:

```ini
[Looker]
base_url=https://lookerstudio.google.com
client_id=[MY_CLIENT_ID]
client_secret=[MY_CLIENT_SECRET]
verify_ssl=True
```

and a

`main.py`

```py
import looker_sdk
sdk = looker_sdk.init40()
sdk.all_dashboards()
```

Running it, I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/tobias/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/looker_sdk/sdk/api40/methods.py", line 4424, in all_dashboards
    self.get(
  File "/home/tobias/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/looker_sdk/rtl/api_methods.py", line 141, in get
    response = self.transport.request(
  File "/home/tobias/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/looker_sdk/rtl/requests_transport.py", line 66, in request
    headers.update(authenticator(transport_options or {}))
  File "/home/tobias/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/looker_sdk/rtl/auth_session.py", line 100, in authenticate
    token = self._get_token(transport_options)
  File "/home/tobias/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/looker_sdk/rtl/auth_session.py", line 87, in _get_token
    self._login(transport_options)
  File "/home/tobias/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/looker_sdk/rtl/auth_session.py", line 148, in _login
    response = self._ok(
  File "/home/tobias/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/looker_sdk/rtl/auth_session.py", line 240, in _ok
    raise error.SDKError(response.value.decode(encoding="utf-8"))
looker_sdk.error.SDKError: )]}'
{"errorStatus":{"code":9}}
```

(same when using `looker_sdk.init31()` instead of `looker_sdk.init40()`)

While debugging, I found

```
)]}'
{"errorStatus":{"code":9}}
```

is the response from the HTTP request (POST) going to `f"{self.settings.base_url}/api/{self.api_version}/login"`, which can be reproduced using `curl`:

```
curl -X POST --url https://lookerstudio.google.com/api/4.0/login --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID_START.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=SECRET_OF_COURSE'
```

Maybe `https://lookerstudio.google.com` is just the wrong `base_url`?

Comment: The docs for the base url are here: https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/api-getting-started#looker_api_path_and_port

Comment: @Ethansocal Thanks, but when visiting https://lookerstudio.google.com/navigation/reporting I don't see an admin panel. Is it only available in the paid version?